# Como implementar el widget o la clase Accordion en un Screen del ScreenManager usando .kv en Kivy (Quiero unir todo para ser mas especifico)

Tags: python, kivy, screen, accordion

##Buenas colegas, me gustaria implementar el widget Accordion que ofrece Kivy junto con su archivo .kv, en un ScreenManager ya que no se como se unen entre si las clases o como deberia hacerlo. Su ayuda es vital para mi, gracias.

1. **main.py**

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion

class FirstWindow (Screen):

```
pass
```

class MenuWindow (Screen):

```
pass
```

class DescripSSWindow (Screen):

```
pass
```

class WindowManager (ScreenManager):

```
pass
```

kv = Builder.load_file('main.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):

```
pass
```

class AwesomeApp(App):

```
def build(self):

    return kv
```

if __ name **=='** main __' :

```
AwesomeApp().run ()
```

2. **main.kv**

WindowManager:

```
FirstWindow:

MenuWindow:

DescripSSWindow:
```

< FirstWindow >:

```
name:"first"


BoxLayout:

    orientation: "vertical"
    size: root.width, root.height
    padding: 60
    spacing: 20


    Label:

        text: "First Screen"
        font_size: 20


    Button:

        text: "Next"
        font_size: 14
        size_hint: .12 , .12
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
        background_color: 1.8,1.3,1.4
        on_release :

            app.root.current= "menu"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
```

< MenuWindow >

```
name:"menu"

BoxLayout:

    orientation: "vertical"
    size: root.width, root.height
    padding: 60
    spacing: 20

    Label:

        text: "Main Screen"
        font_size: 20

    Button:

        text: "Back"
        font_size: 14
        size_hint: .12 , .12
        background_color: 1.7,1.9,1.8
        on_release :
            app.root.current= "first"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"


    Button:

        text: "Next"
        font_size: 14
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.9}
        size_hint: .12 , .12
        background_color: 1.1,1.3,1.3
        on_release :

            app.root.current= "descripcion"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
```

< DescripSSWindow >:

```
name: "descripcion"

BoxLayout:

    orientation: "vertical"
    size: root.width, root.height
    padding: 60
    spacing: 20  

    Label:

        text: "Description"
        font_size: 20   


    Button:

        text: "Back"
        font_size: 14
        size_hint: .12 , .12
        background_color: 1.2,1.6,1.4
        on_release :

            app.root.current= "menu"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"


    Button:

        text: "FirstWindow"
        font_size: 14
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.9}
        size_hint: .12 , .12
        background_color: 1.1,1.7,1.4
        on_release :

            app.root.current= "first"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
```

3. **Codigo accor.py (accordion)**

import kivy

from kivy.app import App

kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion

class Accor(Accordion):

```
pass
```

class AccorApp(App):

```
def build(self):

    return Accor()
```

if __ name __ == '__ main __':

```
AccorApp().run()
```

4. **Codigo accor.kv (accordion)**

< MyImage@Image >:

```
keep_ratio: False
allow_stretch: True
```

< Accor >:

```
orientation: 'vertical'
AccordionItem:

    title: 'Signal'
    MyImage:

        source: '[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]signal.PNG'
AccordionItem:

    title: 'Señales'
    MyImage:

        source: '[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]señales.PNG'
AccordionItem:

    title: 'Portada'
    MyImage:

        source: '[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]portada.PNG'
```

**OUTPUT main.py**

[image: first screen]

[image: main screen]
[image: description screen]

**OUTPUT accor.py**

[image: accordion]

Comment: Muy bonito tu código. Yyy.... cual es tu problema?

Comment: @Christian puedes ayudarme porfa? ya edite la publi.

Comment: Desearía ayudarte pero no sé nada de kivy. Con un poco más de reputación podrás entrar al [chat] donde tal vez más personas puedan guiarte

Comment: ¿Tienes todas las pestañas como archivos diferentes? En kivy puedes definir todas las clases y widgets en el mismo archivo, y en dentro del app.build() estableces cual es el root y como sera el arbol de herencia. Te pdiera ayudar pero el codigo en tu pregunta no se ve bien

Comment: Hola @EdherCarbajal Ya pude implementar el accordion en un screen, respondiendo a tu pregunta tengo todas las pestañas en un mismo file .kv . Simplemente al importar accordion lo heredo a la clase del screen donde deseo que aparezca, ej: class SSWindow(Screen,Accordion):
    pass  ....  Pero tengo algunas dudas sobre una apk que estoy creando, si te gustaria que nos contactaramos avisame.. Gracias compa